# configure mongo with docker on win7

Tags: mongodb, docker, spring-boot

I got a problem with configure connection to mongoDB via docker container in spring boot. I run mongo conteiner and it's waiting for action [print screen of docker terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLeI4.jpg) but in the same time I got error in spring logs [logs screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7OFl.jpg)
Problem appears on win7 while working on udemy course with open source code which You can check on https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-mongodb

Comment: What's the output of `docker ps`? It could be that you're not exposing the port from the container.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, since you're running Docker Machine you need to connect to the docker machine instead of localhost. The IP will usually be `192.168.99.100`, but you can check by executing the `docker-machine ip default` command.

So your mongo connection string will normally be something like `mongodb://192.168.99.100/dbName`

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had same problem and solution for me was to add these two lines to specify port and host of vm and image.
`spring.data.mongodb.host=your_host_ip` 
`spring.data.mongodb.port=your_image_port`
You can find both easly in Kitematic in home tab or by commands. For host_ip in command line enter `ipconfig` command and for image_port `$docker ps` to get container ID and than `$docker inspect <container id>`.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

First do what Strelok said

`docker-machine ip default` and get the ip, 
then start mongo

`docker run -p 27017:27017 -d mongo`.

The port is 27017

---

Then do what trajanesco suggested, edit the application.properties and add these two lines

---

`spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.99.100` # usually the default ip

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```